# NodeJS and HTML DOM not loading Image Background

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

i'm working on an Image Upload System and I want, that the DIV with the Upload Form shows the Uploaded Image.
Everything works fine, the Image is uploaded and the  gets the background-image-path, but it does not show the Background Image, it stays white.

Can you tell me why? Here's my Code:

Server sends

```
data = 'http://1.2.3.4:1111/images/xxxxx.jpg'
```

Client.js

```
success: function(data) {
    var imagemaster = document.getElementById('bilduploadimage2') //get DIV
    imagemaster.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+data+')' //set BG Image
    imagemaster.style.backgroundSize = 'cover'
  }
```

Chrome inspect Element gives:

```
<div class="w3-button w3-white w3-ripple" id="bilduploadimage2" style="background-image: url('http://1.2.3.4:1111/images/xxxxx.jpg'); width: 200px; height: 200px; background-size: cover;"></div>
```

Image Path is working, when I put it in Browser address, but no Image is shown.

Thanks for your help.

Edit:
Also tried with:

```
imagemaster.style = 'background-image: url(' +data+ '); width: 200px; height: 200px; background-size: cover'
```

Image loads only half.

PS.: Sorry for my bad English, I'm German.

Comment: Look at what you write for the Chrome inspect. You have style = "" but inside of your style, you're also using quotes, which end the style attribute. If you had single quotes for your url, it would probably work.

Comment: I think it was just a wrong output of Chrome inspect. Single quotes doesn't change anything..

Answer (score 0):

you need to use background-size:contain in below code.

```
imagemaster.style = 'background-image: url(' +data+ '); width: 200px; height: 
200px; background-size: cover'
```

to see full image you can also bootstrap image class to resize image automatically according to div size.

Comment: The div already has a backgroundImage and the size width 200px and height 200px

Answer (score 0):

Your div has height & width ?

check this:

```
html
<div id="image"></div>

css
#image {
  width: 272px;
  height: 92px;
}

js
(function () {
   var img = document.getElementById('image')
   image.style.backgroundImage =   'url(https://www.google.com.hk/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png)'
  image.style.backgroundSize = 'cover'
})()
```

If the div#image has no height & width, the background-image is don't display.

Comment: Tested it.. with the google link it works, when I set the data Image, it only loads half of the Image. When I copy the Link from Chrome Inspect, the file loads completely.. Inspect says "Image corrupt or truncated.", but the File is ok.

Comment: I Really have to say, i don't know. The File Upload works with the Module "Formidable" and "Multer". The Files are all in ".jpg" Format.